# How to use Java Stream Map a List<Src> to an Object Tgt?

Tags: java, java-stream

First of all, this question is from my real work. I need to solve it and I do some trade off working to realize it unperfect. What's more, I abstract and simplify the basic data structure to avoid sensitive data.

My source and target Object which is `Src` and `Tgt` is as followed:

```java
public class Src {
    int id;
    boolean flag;
    int count;
    // Constructor Getter and Setter methods......
}

public class Tgt {
    int id;
    int true_count;
    int false_count;
    // Constructor Getter and Setter methods......
}
```

Now I have a list of Src Object named `srcList`. I want to combine the list to one Object named `Tgt` which operation is like count how many `flag` in `Src` Object is true or false in the list.

In java8 Stream, I haved tried to use `flatmap` and `map` operator to convert List to one Object like followed code:

```java
public class TestSrc2Tgt {

    public List<Tgt> listSrc2ListTgt(List<Src> srcList){
        Tgt tgt = new Tgt();
        for(Src src : srcList) {
            tgt.setId(src.getId());
            if(src.isFlag()) {
                tgt.setTrue_count(tgt.getTrue_count + src.getCount());
            }
            else {
                tgt.setFalse_count(tgt.getFalse_count + src.getCount());
            }
        }
        /* it is my question and I do not want to use List
            What I want is convert List<Src> to Tgt which is a kind of combine srcList
         */
        List<Tgt> tgtList = new ArrayList<>();
        tgtList.add(tgt);
        return tgtList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TestSrc2Tgt testSrc2Tgt = new TestSrc2Tgt();

        List<Src> srcList = new ArrayList<>();
        srcList.add(new Src(1, true, 15));
        srcList.add(new Src(1, false, 20));
        srcList.add(new Src(1, false, 110));
        srcList.add(new Src(2, true, 40));
        srcList.add(new Src(2, false, 250));
        srcList.add(new Src(2, true, 420));

        // 1. Cluster the id and generate list by id
        Map<Integer, List<Src>> srcMap = srcList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Src::getId, Collectors.toList()));
        // 2. Count how many Src flag is true or false by listSrc2ListTgt method
        // Where I hate is here
        List<Tgt> tgtMaplist =
                srcMap.entrySet().stream().map( e -> {return testSrc2Tgt.listSrc2ListTgt(e.getValue());})
                        .map(item->item.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        tgtMaplist.stream().forEach(t -> {
            System.out.println(t.getId());
            System.out.println(t.getFalse_count());
            System.out.println(t.getTrue_count());
        });
    }
}
```

The code could really work **but I hate the `listSrc2ListTgt()` method and `.map(item->item.get(0))` in getting `List<Tgt> tgtMaplist`**. My idea is a one way converting from `List<Src>` to `Tgt` but not convert from `List<Src>` to `List<Tgt>`(only one element) and then get `Tgt` from `List<Tgt>`. **It is a wasted and unperfect way of realizing**.

In ideal situation

```java
public Tgt listSrc2ListTgt(List<Src> srcList){
    Tgt tgt = new Tgt();
    for(Src src : srcList) {
        tgt.setId(src.getId());
        if(src.isFlag()) {
            tgt.setTrue_count(src.getCount());
        }
        else {
            tgt.setFalse_count(src.getCount());
        }
    }
    return tgt;
}
```

And in main method:

```java
List<Tgt> tgtMaplist = srcMap.entrySet().stream()
                         .map( e -> {return testSrc2Tgt.listSrc2ListTgt(e.getValue());})
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is more comfortable. Because there is no intermediate process taken from the tgtlist by using `.get(0)` method, which seems less redundant. However the ideal code is unable to pass the compiler.

Comment: Well, you should at least follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase and class names in PascalCase.

Comment: What relevance is the `id` field of `Tgt`? Is it just the `id` of the last `Src` in the `srcList`?

Comment: The id is used to Cluster

Comment: `tgt.setTrue_count(src.getCount())` you are setting everytime count in loop? do you want to sum ?

Comment: @User - Upvote don't say Thanks.  o, yes , i am wrong.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideal solution should work, if you return `tgt` instead of `tgtList` inside `ListSrc2ListTgt`:

```java
public Tgt ListSrc2ListTgt(List<Src> srcList) {
    Tgt tgt = new Tgt();
    for(Src src : srcList) {
        tgt.setId(src.getId());
        if(src.isFlag()) {
            tgt.setTrue_count(src.getCount());
        } else {
            tgt.setFalse_count(src.getCount());
        }
    }
    return tgt;
}
```

And to improve the readability and usability of your stream in `main` method:

- don't use `entrySet()` if you don't need the keys. use `values()` instead.
- the lambda can then be shortened with a method reference.

```java
List<Tgt> tgtMaplist = srcMap.values().stream()
        .map(testSrc2Tgt::ListSrc2ListTgt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, I find it. The `.values()` method is more adapt for my situation!

Answer (score 2):

You can map your `Src` into `Tgt` first. Then using `toMap` map by `id` and merge the list of `Tgt` into one using the merge function. Then get the map values in an ArrayList.

```
Map<Integer, Tgt> tgtMap = srcList.stream()
                .map(s -> new Tgt(s.getId(),                     
                                 (s.isFlag() ? s.getCount() : 0),
                                 (s.isFlag() ? 0 : s.getCount())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tgt::getId, e -> e,    
                                    (a, b) -> new Tgt(a.getId(), 
                                                      a.getTrue_count() + b.getTrue_count(), 
                                                      a.getFalse_count() + b.getFalse_count())));

List<Tgt> tgtList = new ArrayList(tgtMap.values()); // Create list from map values
```

Here using `map()` transform `Src` object into `Tgt` object

```
s -> new Tgt(s.getId(), (s.isFlag() ? s.getCount() : 0),(s.isFlag() ? 0 :s.getCount()))
```

And then using `Collectors.toMap` map by `Tgt::getId` which is first parameter of `toMap`.The next one is the key of the map `e -> e` for the whole `Tgt` obj as key. And finally last parameter in the merge function will used for merging two `Tgt` objects into one `Tgt` object so that all values of the same key merged.

```
Collectors.toMap(Tgt::getId,
                 e -> e,
                 (a, b) -> new Tgt(a.getId(), 
                                   a.getTrue_count() + b.getTrue_count(), 
                                   a.getFalse_count() + b.getFalse_count()))
```

To simplify the code with explanations

```
Map<Integer, Tgt> tgtMap = srcList.stream()
                .map(s -> /*transform into Tgt*/)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tgt::getId, e -> e, /*Merge function*/));
```

Comment: Yep, I kown it is fine. And I am try to understand it..... I have never heard the usage of stream like this.... Maybe it is normal to you but it is hard to me. So pleasr describe it more detail...

Comment: I understand that,  I added some explanation hope it helps

Comment: I have got it...But another question. Your method need to new a lot of Tgt objects, would it costs a lot in JVM???

Comment: @dyy.alex Not at all actually, and it's temporary and stream operations are lazy and go one by one in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer to your exact question, but a simpler approach to find the 3 things asked for:

```
int id = srcList.get(srcList.size() - 1).getId();
int true_count = srcList.stream().filter(Src::getFlag).count();
int false_count = srcList.size() - true_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simply way using Java streams:

```
List<Src> srcList = new ArrayList<Src>();
srcList.add(new Src(1, true, 15));
srcList.add(new Src(1, false, 20));
srcList.add(new Src(1, false, 110));
srcList.add(new Src(2, true, 40));
srcList.add(new Src(2, false, 250));
srcList.add(new Src(2, true, 420));

List<Tgt> tgtList = srcList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Src::getId, Collectors.toList()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> 
        new Tgt(e.getKey(), 
                e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(s -> s.getFlag() ? s.getCount() : 0).sum(),
                e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(s -> !s.getFlag() ? s.getCount() : 0).sum())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(tgtList);
```

Here is the output:

```
[Tgt [id=1, true_count=15, false_count=130], Tgt [id=2, true_count=460, false_count=250]]
```

EDIT:
I would prefer to not use streams so we don't loop over the data so many times.

```
Map<Integer, Tgt> tgtMap = new HashMap<Integer, Tgt>();
for (Src src: srcList) {
    Tgt tgt = new Tgt(src.getId(), src.getFlag() ? src.getCount() : 0, !src.getFlag() ? src.getCount() : 0);
    tgtMap.compute(src.getId(), (k, v) -> 
        v == null ? tgt
            : new Tgt(src.getId(), 
                tgt.getTrue_count() + v.getTrue_count(), 
                tgt.getFalse_count() + v.getFalse_count()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this code you need a `Pair` class - either from a library, or you can create it yourself. Instead of custom collector you could use `Collectors.partitioningBy`, but this way it's more efficient.

```
List<Tgt> tgtList = srcList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Src::getId, Collector.of(
                () -> new Pair<>(0L, 0L),
                (pair, src) -> {
                    if (src.isFlag())
                        pair.setKey(pair.getKey() + src.getCount());
                    else
                        pair.setValue(pair.getValue() + src.getCount());
                },
                (pairA, pairB) -> new Pair<>(pairA.getKey() + pairB.getKey(), pairA.getValue() + pairB.getValue())
        )))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new Tgt(entry.getKey(), (int) (long) entry.getValue().getKey(), (int) (long) entry.getValue().getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what is `pair.setKey()`??? I import `javafx.util.Pair` and `java.util`. The method is not in it...

Comment: @dyy.alex the `Pair` from `javafx.util` won't work since it's not mutable. You may use this basic implementation: https://pastebin.com/6EHWDyuy